# Corrupted file when recording using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to record video from the USB WebCam connected to my Windows desktop. Sometimes, I get a mp4 file which I can play using VLC. But sometimes, I can't play mp4 file at all (the file size seems valid video file, 37,528KB).

Here is the command I used:

```
ffmpeg -rtbufsize 1500M -y -f vfwcap -i 0 output.mp4
```

I would like to know:

- why I get a corrupted file sometime with the above command
- how can I fix the 'corrupted' mp4 file?

I have tried the suggestion from bertieb. I get  " `moov atom not found .\corrupt.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input`"

When I open the mp4 file, this is what I see. I don't see 'moov in the header.
[image]. Is there other way to recover the video files? And Should I still switch the format from mp4 to mkv for future capture (since the assumption was the recording was killed before it is properly encoded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short version:

- files are corrupted because you are interrupting to finish the `mp4` encode, switch to something like `mkv` instead.
- 'uncorrupt' by format shifting to another container `ffmpeg -i corrupt.mp4 -c copy not_corrupt.mkv`
- don't use `vfwcap` as it is out of date

---

### Why am I having problems capturing from my USB webcam with `ffmpeg`?

From the [`ffmpeg` docs on `vfwcap`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/vfwcap):

> Note Well this is out of date, these days you can use the -f dshow device to capture from a directshow device.

Since it is out of date, use `-f dshow` instead. From the [DirectShow documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/DirectShow):

> FFmpeg can take input from "directshow" devices on your Windows computer. See the ​[FFmpeg dshow input device documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#dshow) for official documentation. It can accept input from audio, video devices, video capture devices, analog tv tuner devices.

From the [linked `dshow` documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#dshow), you should first find out what the device is under `dshow`:

```
ffmpeg.exe -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

Example output:

```
[dshow @ 0000000002e9bb20] DirectShow video devices (some may be both video and audio devices)
[dshow @ 0000000002e9bb20]  "PC Camera"
[dshow @ 0000000002e9bb20]     Alternative name "@device_pnp_\\?\usb#vid_058f&pid_3880&mi_00#6&218cd81a&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global"
```

using the `"PC Camera"` found by the previous command:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="PC Camera" -y output.mkv
```

*(I would back off on using `-rtbufsize` initially, as there are some [caveats noted](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide) for using it with `dshow` devices`)*

I would suggest using `mkv` over `mp4` as my guess is you are not doing a fixed-time encode but instead terminating `ffmpeg` with <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>; this prevents `ffmpeg` from writing certain atoms to the video container and **likely why the file is corrupted**<sup>1</sup>. `mkv` can be interrupted at will<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>: You could test this by format-shifting the corrupted mp4s:
`ffmpeg -i corrupt.mp4 -c copy not_corrupt.mkv`. If that doesn't work, [another answer on SU by sparrowt recommends `untrunc`](https://superuser.com/a/596402)</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup>: Tested using `ffmpeg version N-72939-g5b0f55a` on Windows, and a random cheap webcam I happened to have lying around</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answers.  I get this error when I try to format shifting " moov atom not found
.\corrupt.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input"

Comment: Sounds like the files are indeed truncated (from Ctrl+C or however), [another answer on here recommends untrunc](http://superuser.com/a/596402); which I will edit into the body of the answer if that works for you

Comment: mkv doesn't seem to be tolerant of unexpected stops either... i tried using ffmpeg to record to mkv and killed it during the process and the mkv file was also unplayable.  what format should i record directly to so it won't be corrupted if the process is killed or interrupted?