# How to reencode or repair a video on Ubuntu/Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg, linux-mint, screen-recorder

I recently tried to make a video with kazam, until the inevitable "I'm out of storage so Kazam goes crazy and loses video" occurs. I regained storage, and used photorec to recover the video, and I got it again, but there's a major problem: The video is broken-ish. The first few seconds play, but then it stops and my computer freezes, crashing the program and unfreezing. Is there a way to repair it with ffmpeg? It's 1.9GB, so there's stuff inside.

So is there a way to fix it? So far, untrunc doesn't work.

Comment: You're better off trying a video repair [utility](http://superuser.com/a/1033364/114058).

Comment: @Mulvya is there a Linux version?

Comment: There is another utility, [untrunc](https://github.com/ponchio/untrunc) but I haven't used it.

Comment: @Mulvya It says it requires a similar unbroken video. Why, and does just SIMILAR count? I only have broken copies of that video I tried to record. If it could just be any similar video though, then it might work.

Comment: Similar means any video taken from the same device with the same settings. You can just record a new short video.

Comment: @Mulvya, I tried, but it said about a header missing, invalid length, and a wrong match in track. It has found 1825 packets though, even if it hasn't created a recovered file. BTW, I made this comment again to ping you.

Comment: I'm thinking then that photorec didn't recover the data properly.

Comment: @Mulvya maybe the converter program you mentioned eariler could work?

Comment: @Mulvya Actually the program did "recover" the video, but only the beginning that worked right anyways.