# How can I recover a corrupted video saved to my Android phone?

Tags: video, android, vlc-media-player, virtualdub

I recorded a video with my Android phone (Blackberry Priv) and the phone shut down unexpectedly (probably because of battery overheating). The video file was not saved correctly and I cannot play it on the phone. I was able to copy the file to my Windows computer but can't play it there either. VLC can't open it either, says it couldn't recognize the video format.

I can see the video format in other video files recorded by my phone. Is there some application which could restore format information for the corrupted video file if I tell it what the format should be? Maybe VirutalDub?

The other video files are recorded in this format:
[image]

Or is there any other way to recover the corrupted video file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open and repair an m4v or mp4 video file?](https://superuser.com/questions/417100/how-to-open-and-repair-an-m4v-or-mp4-video-file). Seems like [Untrunc](https://github.com/ponchio/untrunc) can help.

Comment: If you know the video format, it might help a lot in suggesting things to try - yet what works depends on how corrupted or truncated the file is

Comment: @planetmaker I would guess that the video is an H.264 encoded MP4 since that is what the majority of phones record in. So the file is most likely truncated and not properly closed so using software like Untrunc could help.

Comment: Untrunc doesn't seem to have Windows binaries. You think I'll have to run it in a dockered Linux?

Comment: It looks like I can't post an answer to my question because someone marked it as a duplicate. Either way, what fixed the problem for me effortlessly was the Android app **MP4Fix**. Apparently, it knows the typical Android formats and problems and can fix them right in the phone. It then shows you the fixed video and asks you to pay cca. 6EUR so you have to decide if the video is worth it.