# how to fix mp4 file with missing moov atom?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, vlc-media-player, mp4

I have a video file (mp4) and I want to load it in a video editor. However, it shows an error which says, "file format not recognized." So, I used the `file` command and the output is just `data`. `ffmpeg` shows an error `moov atom not found`. Both Windows Media Player and VLC are unable to play the video, however, mpc-hc is able to open the file without any issues.

So how is mpc-hc able to play the video if there's no moov atom? How do I fix the file so it can be opened by other programs?

Thanks!

Comment: Check if [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/417100/how-to-open-and-repair-an-m4v-or-mp4-video-file) helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open and repair an m4v or mp4 video file?](https://superuser.com/questions/417100/how-to-open-and-repair-an-m4v-or-mp4-video-file)